# charlower with gcc

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, ctype

I am trying to convert the following code from msvc to gcc

```
    #define ltolower(ch) CharLower((LPSTR)(UCHAR)(ch))
    char * aStr;
    * aStr = (char)ltolower(*aStr);
```

This code is giving a compiler error: cast from ‘CHAR*’ to ‘char’ loses precision

My understanding is that tolower(int) from c wouldn't convert the whole string.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cast in **CharLower** is raising that error. Before doing that, you need to set the high order byte of the pointer passed to **CharLower** equals to ZERO.

From MSDN reference on the function:

> If the operand is a character string,
>   the function returns a pointer to the
>   converted string. Because the string
>   is converted in place, the return
>   value is equal to lpsz.
>
> If the operand is a single character,
>   the return value is a 32-bit value
>   whose high-order word is zero, and
>   low-order word contains the converted
>   character.

Something like this might work:

```
#define ltolower(ch) CharLower(0x00ff & ch)
```

If you are using a C++ compiler, you might also need a CAST operator:

```
#define ltolower(ch) CharLower((LPTSTR)(0x00ff & ch))
```

Haven't tested it though...

Comment: that didn't work exactly.  But thanks for the explanation.
I am just going to rewrite the code using tolower()

Comment: I was able to just do: <pre>
  * aStr = (char)(int)ltolower(*aStr); </pre>